# how to add path for custom object in salesforce?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, administration

I am trying to add path for my custom object but I could not find my custom object in that list. It is showing only the standard object. Could you please help me to fix this?

Comment: You tagged your question "Community". Are you working within Salesforce Communities here? Is the "list" you refer to in Path Settings? Does the custom object contain a picklist field? More information will make answers possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have atleast one picklist field in your custom object to have path for that object.
Please check and let me know if it still doesnt appear.

Comment: Provide complete answer to the question.  Can you add more details to your answer.

Comment: Hope the answer gives enough information for the question asked above. Let me know if it is not understandable